# Regex, replace a single character

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

I have a string:

```
((a*e*(math.cos(ai+la))^(2))/(l))+((a*12*e*i*(math.sin(ai+ni))^(2))/(l^(3)))...
```

I need to replace "a" whit capital "A" but strings "ai, math, la..." should stay like they are.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Is this regex used by Lua, or is it used for your text editor. The regex flavor makes a big difference. I'm not sure `\b` exists in Lua.

Comment: @4castle I use SublimeText for Lua, using "replace" tool I want to replace all single characters "a" to uppercase "A" but not change the word that have in them letter "a"...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a word boundary assertion `\b`.

```
\ba\b
```